# hazelcast open source cost?

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I am new to hazelcast and want to use the replicated map to share data between two microservices. Using spring-boot-starter cache with following two modules. Is it open source/free ?

```
  `enter code here`<!-- Core hazelcast module -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
        <artifactId>hazelcast</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- hazelcast-spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
        <artifactId>hazelcast-spring</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: Yes, it is.

Long answer: It's Apache as the [LICENSE](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/blob/master/LICENSE) file on GitHub clearly states.

[image]